# GTK configuration source

Tags: configuration, gtk, gtk#, gconf

I am developing cross platform(Windows, Linux) desktop application using Mono and Gtk#. Application will have some configuration. And I have a question about storing configuration data. Where is the best place for it? I was going to use sqlite db for it, but I found that gtk# also support gconf. 
Does mono gconf wrapper works on Windows? And if yes, where it will store configuration? Or gconf isn't good place for cross platform application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry classes work on mono, They may be of some help to you if you only want simple settings.

See [Mono: Application Portability](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Portability#Registry_Usage)